# elasticsearch query text field with length of value more than 20

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I would like to query name filed with length of value(text) is more than 20 by using the following but not working:

```
GET /groups/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : "_source.name.values.length() > 20"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the error msg is :

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "compile error",
        "script_stack": [
          "_source.name.values.lengt ...",
          "^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "_source.name.values.length() > 5",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "groups",
        "node": "exBbDVGeToSDRzLLmOh8-g",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"must\" : [\n      {\n        \"script\" : {\n          \"script\" : {\n            \"inline\" : \"_source.name.values.length() > 5\",\n            \"lang\" : \"painless\"\n          },\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"disable_coord\" : false,\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
          "index_uuid": "_VH1OfpdRhmd_UPV7uTNMg",
          "index": "groups",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "compile error",
            "script_stack": [
              "_source.name.values.lengt ...",
              "^---- HERE"
            ],
            "script": "_source.name.values.length() > ",
            "lang": "painless",
            "caused_by": {
              "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
              "reason": "Variable [_source] is not defined."
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

no idea how should i fix it...

fyi: version of  es  is 5.4.0

I don't know the following issue related:
Painless script_fields don't have access to a _source variable #20068
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20068

Comment: Have you tried `ctx._source` instead of `_source` ?

Comment: ctx._source doesn't works for me.

Comment: GET /china_groups/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : "doc['name'].values.size() > 5 "
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

this seems works for me...

Comment: That will not measure the length of the whole field only the number of tokens in your `name` field.

Comment: If I were you, I would index the length of the field in another field (e.g. `nameLength`)  at indexing time, so that you can simply use a `range` query at search time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and most optimal way to handle this is to also index another field with the length of the `name` field, let's call it `nameLength`. That way you shift the burden of computing the length of the name field at indexing time instead of having to do it (repeatedly) at query time.

So at indexing time if you have a `name` field like `{"name": "A big brown fox"}`, then you create a new field with the length of the name field, such as `{"name": "A big brown fox", "nameLength": 15}`.

At query time, you'll be able to use a simple and quick `range` query on the `nameLength` field:

```
GET /groups/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "range" : {
                    "nameLength": {
                       "gt": 20
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`params._source.name.length() > 20`

In case this is a rare query, that's probably ok to do. Otherwise you should add a field for the name length, and use the `range` query.

Comment: this seems return the number of tokens after analysed cause name field is text

Comment: You're right, sorry about that! I've edited with something that actually works. I do strongly suggest you consider the other answer though (using a separate field to store the length). Unless it's very rare, if you're using script queries in ES, probably your data model is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. i should probably rethink the model i am using.